# What to do when selecting cell with no JSON response associated

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I'm getting a **response back from a web service API** like so:

```
{
    "springs": [{
        "name": "springName",
        "leafs": [{
            "name": "leafName",
            "towns": [{
                "name": "townName",
            },{
            "name": "leafName2",
            },{
```

I'm listing all of the `Leafs` in a `LeafViewController` Table View, and if the `Leaf` has a list of `Towns` associated with it, then it segues to the `TownViewController` Table View to list the associated `Towns`.

I have all of that correct in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Spring *spring = [springs objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    Leaf *leaf = [sport.leafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = leaf.shortName;

    return cell;
}
```

My question is that **sometimes there is no `Town` associated with a `Leaf`**, in which case I need to check that so if that `Leaf` cell is pressed then I can pop back to the Main View Controller instead of going to the next View Controller that lists `Town`s.

Right now, if I select a `Leaf` cell with no `Town`s associated with it, then it segues to the `TownViewController` which is blank, since there are no towns associated.

**How would I check the JSON response so I know whether to segue to next TownViewController or pop back to `MainViewController`?**

I can post any extra code necessary, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Spring *spring = [springs objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    Leaf *leaf = [sport.leafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(leaf.town)
         //Do whatever
    else
         //Do something different
}
```

This obviously depends on you have your leaf object correctly configured for this.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  This makes a lot of sense, I'm gonna give it a shot tonight-